# How to Change Laravel Nova Lens Name

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-nova

In laravel Nova resources I can change the resource name with label function but in Lens, with the same function it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Code:

```
public static function label(): string
{
    return 'Asistencias Empleados';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lens we don't use labels for changing name we have this method name

```
public function name():string
{
    return __('Most Valuable Users');
}
```

Comment: It worked for me, thank you very much. I didn't find this in the Nova documentation.

Comment: Is documented in the localization part check this link
https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/customization/localization.html#lenses